# Eloquent Javascript chapter 10 modules

Tags: javascript, module, eloquent

I am at the end of the modules chapter, but I don't really understand the whenDepsLoaded() part of this code. Could someone explain it for me please?

for example, what does this line do?

> if (!deps.every(function(m) { return m.loaded; }))
>         return;

And this line?

> myMod.onLoad.forEach(function(f) { f(); });

```
var defineCache = Object.create(null);
    var currentMod = null;

    function getModule(name) {
      if (name in defineCache)
        return defineCache[name];

      var module = {exports: null,
                    loaded: false,
                    onLoad: []};
      defineCache[name] = module;
      backgroundReadFile(name, function(code) {
        currentMod = module;
        new Function("", code)();
      });
      return module;
    }


    function define(depNames, moduleFunction) {
      var myMod = currentMod;
      var deps = depNames.map(getModule);

      deps.forEach(function(mod) {
        if (!mod.loaded)
          mod.onLoad.push(whenDepsLoaded);
      });

      function whenDepsLoaded() {
        if (!deps.every(function(m) { return m.loaded; }))
          return;

        var args = deps.map(function(m) { return m.exports; });
        var exports = moduleFunction.apply(null, args);
        if (myMod) {
          myMod.exports = exports;
          myMod.loaded = true;
          myMod.onLoad.forEach(function(f) { f(); });
        }
      }
      whenDepsLoaded();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> for example, what does this line do?

```
if (!deps.every(function(m) { return m.loaded; })) return;
```

It checks if there is at least one dependency that has not been loaded.

[Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/every) basically iterates over the whole array and invokes the "test" function that you pass to it. In this example, it check if an object has `loaded` property set to a truthy value. But because there is a negation in from of that `every` call, it means that if **not** every dependency has been loaded, it will return from the function.

> And this line?

```
myMod.onLoad.forEach(function(f) { f(); });
```

Since `mod.onLoad` contains an Array of functions, it simply invokes these functions one by one.

You should look at [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/forEach) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

#### Work step by step from the inside out

Start at the inside of the puzzling statement and work outwards. That way there is less to think about at each stage.

```
if (!deps.every(function(m) { return m.loaded; })) return;
```

The innermost part is `function(m) { return m.loaded; }`. This is a function that takes an object and returns its "loaded" property, i.e. whether it is loaded.

The `.every` function takes an array and only answers true if all the elements in the array pass the test inside the parentheses.

Therefore `deps.every( ..... )` takes the `deps` array and tests all its elements, for the presence of the ".loaded" property being true. If all of them are true, which means in practical terms that all the dep[endencie]s are loaded, then `deps.every...` is true.

By making the if statement test for `!deps.every`, that statement is looking to see if ANY of the deps are NOT loaded, and if so the entire function returns at that stage.

#### myMod.onload

```
myMod.onLoad.forEach(function(f) { f(); });
```

Here, `function (f) { f(); };` is defining an anonymous function whose input is another function, and which executes that (other) function. For example, if you pass the anonymous function an input of `console.log("hello")`, it will print "hello" to the console.

`myMod.onLoad` is a list of functions that are designed to be run when the module loads. `myMod.onLoad.forEach()` is a way of iterating automatically over all of those functions, and feeding them into the anonymous function described above, which arranges for those functions to be executed.

The overall effect is that the statement scans through all the functions listed in myMod.onLoad, and executes them.